# Excel : Delete duplicate occurrences based on ColumnA & ColumnB values.

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010, frequency, excel-2013, countif

The excel file has column A & B. Column C is what I need to create.

Condition is when "column A" (Email) is not empty, then I need to keep the first occurrence of ColumnA + ColumnB. All other occurences can be deleted.

I tried with various options such as COUNTIF and FREQUENCY but not getting anywhere.

Please let me know the best approaches.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: so you are trying to delete the duplicates? i mean, put 'delete' in front of those which are duplicate, otherwise, yes? right?

Comment: @AHC : Yes, keep the first occurrence of ColumnA+ColumnB and remove other matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to formula, select the columns in which you are looking for the duplicates then go to your **DATA** tab in excel, and click on **remove duplicates** in the data tools section.  There you go!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need to delete the duplicates only when EmailID column is not empty (not blank). I had tried the above earlier and it deletes all empty email addresses also. I guess I have to prefill those empty email address with something like BLANKEMAIL1, BLANKEMAIL2, BLANKEMAIL3 for all blank email records and then run your suggestion. Just figuring out if there is a way to prefill all blank email addresses with some unique value? Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Please ignore above post as I am working on getting results into column as per my original post. Reason is we need to find out how many duplicates were found for emailID+CompanyName combination. Please let me know.